# Remove broken resource relationships between pages and page layouts

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, orphan

We have a page layout that we want to delete from  a site collection but according to moss it is still referenced by some publishing pages. The pages that are apparently using the page layout are no longer in the pages library that it says they are.

In the manage content and structure view if I look at the resources that are using this page layout it has a number of pages with a link icon and the check boxes next to them are grayed out.

I'm assuming that using the api I can clean up these orphaned resource relationships.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Guys, it seems like some of these pages have ended up in this state after a content db move. I can see the pages in the all_docs table but the listid they relate to does not exist. Is there a good way to clean up these redundant pages?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps these pages are in the recycle bin. It's worth clearing the bin and see if that makes any difference.

Or perhaps these pages are in a draft state and you can't see them due to the permissions assigned to the account you are using to login.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tool linked to from [Stefan's post here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/03/12/common-error-situation-with-when-using-backup-restore-to-transfer-a-database-to-a-new-farm-on-moss-2007.aspx) might be a good starting point. It might depend on how your data ended up like this though, it could be that Stefan's tool is just doing a find/replace when you really need to do something more conditional.

Probably worth taking a look though.

Comment: Guys, it seems like some of these pages have ended up in this state after a content db move. I can see the pages in the all_docs table but the listid they relate to does not exist. Is there a good way to clean up these redundant pages?

Answer (score 1):

In SP2007 you can use SharePoint designer to create a directory, say /_catalog/masterpage/delete and move the pagelayouts to that directory. Then you can delete the 'delete' directory and you pagelayout's are gone!

Note. any referenced pages are now broken. This does not work in SP2010.

> > In the manage content and structure view if I look at the resources that are using this page layout it has a number of pages with a link icon and the check boxes next to them are grayed out.

These are probably pages that are never checked in, created by other users. You can reclaim them using list settings of the pages document library. (you must be site collection admin)